# Don't redirect one directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with my custom `.htaccess` redirection.

Here are my `.htaccess` rules:

```
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm

  RewriteEngine on
  # 301 redirect to domain without 'www.'
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/www\.example\.com/public/www/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/www/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cms\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cms\.example\.com/public/core/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cms\.example\.com/tmp/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/core/$1 [L]
```

So everything from main directory is redirected to `public/...`.
Is it possible to not redirect one directory in main directory?

For example:

`http://example.com/something` will redirect me to `public/www/something`
but I want it point to `root_folder/something`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this condition into  your rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something`.

Your rule then should look like this, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/www\.mydomain\.com/public/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/www/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent "one directory" from being rewritten then it would be more efficient to do this check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, rather than add another condition. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^something /public/www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However, it would be better to reorder your rules so that you are performing your `/public/www/` check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead, since this is the most common. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/something
RewriteRule !^/public/www/ /public/www/$1 [L]
```

(Maybe it was an issue with your exemplified code, but you had unnecessarily duplicated the `HTTP_HOST` check.)